# Delete file from firebase storage using sketchware

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I managed to get files to upload to my firebase storage bucked but how can I delete the file within sketchwere.

I enter the URL of the storage bucket where the file is located but my application keeps crashing with error "The storage URI cannot be parsed."

Any ideas?
I think I am entering the wrong URL.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, here's an example on how to delete file in your firebase storage using the `Android SDK` : [Delete](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/delete-files).

```
// Create a storage reference from our app
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();

// Create a reference to the file to delete
StorageReference desertRef = storageRef.child("images/desert.jpg");

// Delete the file
desertRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        // File deleted successfully
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw that although i am using sketchware which uses blocks instead of code. The block asks me for the url of where the file is located and I think i am entering the wrong url. I dont know what url to enter into the block.

Comment: Your url should look like this : `gs://PROJECT_ID.appspot.com/FOLDER/FILE`.

Comment: I was hoping someone here knows sketchware who can help me.

Comment: I entered exactly what you just told me before and i still get that error. That's why i am so confused

Comment: For the file name i use a variable instead of an actual string but I cant image that would make a difference

Comment: I don't know how sketchware works, but here's a video on how to setup `Firebase Storage` [Setup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TdQNVL3nvhU)

Comment: Sorted, I was being an idiot. I forgot to to put an "/" at the end of gs://PROJECT_ID.appspot.com

Comment: Your answer is perfect, I just forgot to add that last /.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying the image from a listmap, use "get value at position of listmap" block to get the URL of the image.  You must add a firebase storage component to that activity matching the path of the image.

I'd you are using a firebase reference code to display image,  use the reference code to get the value of the image url to a string variable.

You must also make sure you have a firebase auth component added to that activity, and make sure your rules allow writing to that path in storage and database.

Also, make sure you are using the firebase storage "delete file from url" block.